# Determine the size of a TextObj in ZedGraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a ZedGraph pane, and have added a TextObj to it. Now, the TextObj has a property called `Location`, which has properties `Height` and `Width`. However, as far as I can see, the values for both of there are always 0. What can I do to determine the dimensions of the TextObj? Preferrably it should be in graph coordinates (like `Location.X` etc).

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure anything out with this? Running into the same issue now...

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same answer but have you tried

Dim textobjMyText As New TextObj("some text", 0.001, 0.001, CoordType.PaneFraction, AlignH.Left, AlignV.Top)

This will place the text in the top - left coroner once I have added it to the masterpane. the 0.001 is a very small offset

zg1.MasterPane.GraphObjList.Add(textobjMyText)

Hope this helps

Comment: Not sure how this should help.. I tried it, but it still gives me a TextObj with 0 height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following this should place an text somewhere in the centre of your graph pane you can then adjust to get the text where you wish it to appear.  I have used the code below with the values of 002 0 and 0.97 to just the text to appear at the bottom left. But if you get the text in the centre makes a small adjustment you should see how it works

```
'Add footer text

 Dim TextObjCanute As New TextObj("some footer text", 0.5, 0.5, CoordType.PaneFraction, AlignH.Left, AlignV.Top)
TextObjCanute.FontSpec.Border.IsVisible = False
TextObjCanute.FontSpec.Fill.IsVisible = True
TextObjCanute.FontSpec.Size = 8
zg1.MasterPane.GraphObjList.Add(TextObjCanute) 'add footer to pane
```

I have adjusted the values as follows

```
' Dim TextObjCanute As New TextObj("footer text", 0.002, 0.97, CoordType.PaneFraction, AlignH.Left, AlignV.Top)
```

In the text now appears in the bottom left-hand corner